# Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence suppose there exists $0 <\lambda < 1$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence. Suppose there exists $0 < \lambda < 1$ such that

$|a_{n+1} - a_n| \leq \lambda|a_n - a_{n-1}|$ for all $n >1$. Prove that $\{a_n\}$ converges.

I seem to be stuck. If I handle this like I would any other distance or metric space problem I would have the an cancel out. I think it might either be my algebra or the lambda that is throwing me off.

Comment: Have you heard of Cauchy sequences?

Comment: Yes that for some reason didnt even cross my mind. Thanks for that this should be much easier now

Answer (score 2):

Show that $|a_{n+1} - a_n| \le \lambda^{n-1}|a_2 - a_1|$ for all $n > 1$. Then if $m > n$,

$$|a_m - a_n| = \left|\sum_{i = n}^{m-1} (a_{i+1} - a_i)\right| \le \sum_{i = n}^{m-1}|a_{i+1} - a_i| \le \sum_{i = n}^{m-1}\lambda^{i-1}|a_2 - a_1| \tag{*}$$

Since $0 < \lambda < 1$, the series $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \lambda^{i-1}|a_2 - a_1|$ converges. Hence, given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an index $N$ that makes the right-most side of $(*)$ less than $\epsilon$ whenever $m > n > N$. Therefore, $\{a_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, and consequently $\{a_n\}$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$|a_{n+1}-a_n|<\lambda|a_n-a_{n-1}|<\lambda^2|a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}|<...$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$|a_{n+1}-a_n|\le\lambda|a_n+a_{n-1}|\le\lambda^2|a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}|\le\ldots\le\lambda^{n-1}|a_2-a_1|$$